# Ember 2.0 not live reloading

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I created a new app using the ember-cli.  It creates the project just fine.  I updated the 'bower.json' file to use 2.0.0 for both Ember and Ember Data and installed them.  The core of my application setup works how it should.

When I do 'ember serve', my application opens at localhost:4200 but is constantly showing the reload gif on the tab and the status bar at the bottom of the screen continues to show 'waiting for localhost...'.  The 'Welcome To Ember' text shows.  Any changes I make are not live reloaded in my browser, however, a hard reload shows the changes even when just trying to edit the application.hbs file.  Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: What OS are you using? is your text editor watching for changes in `/tmp`?

Comment: I had a problem with live reload some time ago. I did some reinstall of liveReload and Watchman and added this to .ember-cli file: ```"liveReaload" : true,
  "watcher" : "polling"```. Then it worked. Still don't know what was the issue though.

Comment: I'm on Windows.  Doing "ember serve host 0.0.0.0" fixed the problem for me.  I tried what you suggested in editing the .ember-cli file but it didn't work.  Apparently it's a known bug right now.  https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/5123.  Btw, I don't understand why people downvote and don't give some explanation as to why.  So annoying.  This is the only solution that worked for me after only finding 2 other posts about it that didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you on windows? It sounds like this bug that is currently being worked on.

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/5123

Comment: Thank you!  As gmurphey suggested, doing "ember serve host 0.0.0.0" fixed the problem for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

For me `ember serve --lrp 9000` worked and fixed live-reload.

(I tried the other suggestion to use `ember serve host 0.0.0.0` and it stopped the "loading" spinner, but live-reload still did not work.)